# VBA　シート1のA7、C7、シート2のA2の"2020"03"01"の数値を合算させyyyymmddの"20200301"と数値でセルに表示する手法

Tags: windows-10, vba, excel

**前提・実現したいこと**
VBAで転換マクロツールを創っています。
いま、画像に示すようにVBAでシート1のA7、C7、シート2のA2の3つのセルの数値を合算させて、
シート2のA2のセルに"20200301"と表示するVBAを組んでいます。

40行目に`str = FormatYYYYMMDD(Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A7"), Sheets(Sheet1).Range("C7"), Range("A2"))`というコードを追加した所、
38行目の`sh.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Work\出力先\test.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV`のコードで、1004エラーが出ます。

原因・改善法などおわかりになれば教えてください。

[image: イメージ[![画像の説明をここに入力][VBA]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][シート１]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][シート２]

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

```
実行時エラー'1004'
'SaveAs'メソッドは失敗しました:_'Worksheet'オブジェクト
```

**該当のソースコード**

```
Public Sub FileUpload() 'ファイル選択ダイアログモジュール

    Dim fType As Variant
    Dim fPath As Variant
    Dim str As String 'yyyymmdd出力用

'※選択できるファイルの種類はエクセルファイルのみ
    fType = "Microsoft Excelブック,*.xls?" '※

'ファイル参照ダイアログの表示
    fPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(fType, , "") 'fType = fPath。
    Debug.Print fPath
    If fPath = False Then
'ダイアログでキャンセルボタンが押された場合は処理を終了します
       Exit Sub 'Endで強制終了はよろしくない
    End If

    Dim Target As Workbook 'コンバートモジュール
    Set Target = Workbooks.Open(fPath)

    'これをセル抜き出しから数値抜出に変更⇔循環小数エラーの解決｡
    Target.Sheets(1).Range("G2").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2")
    Target.Sheets(1).Range("H2").Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A3")

    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2") = FormatYYYYMMDD(Sheet1!A7, Sheet1!C7, A2)
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A3") = FormatYYYYMMDD(Sheet1!A7, Sheet1!C7, A3)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2:A3").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2:A3").Value '数式→数値変換
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A2:A3").NumberFormatLocal = "yyyymmdd"

    'yyyymmdd変換、半早のスケジュール登録すれば完成。

     Target.Close '※開いたブックは閉じておく
     Set Target = Nothing '念のため、変数開放

Dim sh As Worksheet 'csv保存モジュール
Set sh = Worksheets(2)
sh.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Work\出力先\test.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV

str = FormatYYYYMMDD(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C7").Value, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value)

MsgBox (str) 'yyyymmdd出力用

End Sub

Public Function FormatYYYYMMDD(ByVal yyyy As Variant, ByVal mm As Variant, ByVal dd As Variant) As String
    FormatYYYYMMDD = Format(yyyy * 10000 + mm * 100 + dd, "00000000")
End Function
```

**試したこと**
別サイトで回答を貰い、40行目のstrのコードを、`"str = FormatYYYYMMDD(Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A7"), Sheets(Sheet1).Range("C7"), Range("A2"))"`と、
`"str = FormatYYYYMMDD(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C7").Value, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value)"`
の、2通り試したのですが、
どちらも同じように38行目のSaveAsメソッドで1004エラーを吐いてしまします。

もしおわかりになればお教え頂けると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

**補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）**
Excle2016,Windows10

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/257159

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ [DateSerial関数、分割された年月日を1つの年月日に結合する(Excel VBA)](https://www.diamondblog.jp/official/omura/2016/02/01/%E5%88%86%E5%89%B2%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E5%B9%B4%E6%9C%88%E6%97%A5%E3%82%921%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AE%E5%B9%B4%E6%9C%88%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AB%E7%B5%90%E5%90%88%E3%81%99%E3%82%8Bexcel-vba%E3%80%81dateseria/), [Excel VBA 分割された年月日を表す文字列を結合して日付データにする](https://kosapi.com/post-6391/)

Comment: やりたいことは「日付(を表す)文字列の操作」なのかもしれませんが、エラーの内容は「シートの保存」に関するもので、説明が食い違っているように思います。もう少し問題点を切り分けてみることをおすすめします。

Comment: 特定のシートを指定したSaveAsは出来なくて、新BookとかにコピーしてSaveAsらしいですね。[特定のシートだけを別ファイルで保存するマクロ（VBA）](https://www.excelvba.club/entry/2016/10/30/222658), [CSVの出力（書き出し）方法](https://excel-ubara.com/excelvba5/EXCEL120.html), [備忘録：エクセルVBA　・指定したシートをCSVファイルに出力する](http://adbaiz.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/03/09/111522), [EXCEL VBA EXCELファイル・ワークブック・アクティブシートの保存・上書き保存・選択保存　（SaveAs・GetSaveAsFilename）](https://akira55.com/saveas/)

Comment: supaさん　編集ありがとうございます。
htbさん　誘導ありがとうございます。
kunifさん　2度もコメント頂きありがとうございます。今"Excel VBA 分割された年月日を表す文字列を結合して日付データにする""を試しています。"特定のシートを指定したSaveAsは出来ない"とのことも調べてみます。
cubick♦さん　ありがとうございます。調べているのですがどうもこの「シートの保存」でエラーが出ているのではなく、その下部の40行目のstrのコードがおかしいことをVBA側でSaveASメソッド(周辺)がおかしくてエラーだよって言っているのかな？と仮説を立て調べています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一応解決しました。
VBAをスリム化して書き直し再現性をチェックして試行錯誤した所、
csv上書き処理をキャンセルする際に1004エラーが出るということを突き止めました。
上書きすればエラーは出ず、またcsvファイルを削除して保存する際もエラーが出ません。

根本的な原因、上書き処理をキャンセルする際に何故エラーが出るのか、エラーが出なくなる為の対処法はまだ未解決ですが、全体の開発を進めてから後程この仕様を解決することにしました。
ご協力ありがとうございます。